# Error in fetching values from database in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I am fetching value from table sessionapps in my cakephp application.

I have index.ctp file as follows

```
<table>
<tr><td>ID</td><td>Title</td><td>Post</td><td>Actions</td><td>Created On</td></tr>
<?php foreach ($sessionapps as $post): ?>
<tr><td><?php echo $post[Sessionapp][id];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data->Html->link($post[Sessionapp][title],array('controller'=>'sessionapp','action'=>'view',$post[Sessionapp][id]));?></td>
    <td><?php echo $post[Sessionapp][post];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $this->Html->link('Edit Post ', array('action' => 'editarticle', $post[Sessionapp][id]));?></td>
    <td><?php echo $post[Sessionapp][created];?></td></tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

And i have created its controller sessionapps_controller.php and added action index in it as follows

```
function index()
    {
               $this->set('sessionapps', $this->Sessionapp->find('all'));
    }
```

But it is not working and giving error

```
Notice (8): Use of undefined constant Sessionapp - assumed 'Sessionapp' [APP/views/sessionapps/index.ctp, line 14]

Notice (8): Use of undefined constant id - assumed 'id' [APP/views/sessionapps/index.ctp, line 14]
```

My array $sessionapps as follows

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Sessionapp] => Array ( [id] => 1 [title] => The title [body] => This is the post body. [postby] => [created] => 2013-01-15 11:35:13 [modified] => ) ) [1] => Array ( [Sessionapp] => Array ( [id] => 2 [title] => A title once again [body] => And the post body follows. [postby] => [created] => 2013-01-15 11:35:13 [modified] => ) ) [2] => Array ( [Sessionapp] => Array ( [id] => 3 [title] => Title strikes back [body] => This is really exciting! Not. [postby] => [created] => 2013-01-15 11:35:13 [modified] => ) ) ) 1
```

Comment: Did you try the answer I posted below in your view file. You are not correctly referencing the array elements. Simply replace the foreach loop with the one I posted.

Comment: Now everything is showing but no post column showing..

Comment: can you paste the array $sessionapps here?

Comment: @HarmeetKaur plz see the array in edited question

Comment: @HarmeetKaur problem solved :) i m wrngly using post in place of body ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be like this.

```
<?php foreach ($sessionapps as $post): ?>
<tr><td><?php echo $post['Sessionapp']['id'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data->Html->link($post['Sessionapp']['title'],array('controller'=>'sessionapp','action'=>'view',$post['Sessionapp']['id']));?></td>
    <td><?php echo $post['Sessionapp']['post'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $this->Html->link('Edit Post ', array('action' => 'editarticle', $post['Sessionapp']['id']));?></td>
    <td><?php echo $post['Sessionapp']['created'];?></td></tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: @Usman ok. then try print_r($sessionapps); What result does it give?

Comment: @Usman The query $this->Sessionapp->find('all') is not giving result. so $sessionapps does not contain the elements you want to show in view file